# Minimum Mean Square Error (MMSE) and Mutual Information (I)

Tags: pr.probability

Consider this setting:

$Y=X+N$

where $N$ is a Gaussian standard random variable and $X$ is another arbitrarily distributed r.v. You can think of this $X$ as a message being transmitted over an AWGN channel the output of which is the r.v. $Y$. I am wondering if anybody can introduce me some good resources on the connection between $MMSE = E[(X- E[X|Y])^2]$ and mutualinput-output information, namely $I(X:Y)= E[log \frac {p_{X,Y}}{p_X p_Y}]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be extremely relevant

"Mutual Information and Minimum Mean-square Error in Gaussian Channels" by Dongning Guo, Shlomo Shamai (Shitz), and Sergio Verdu

http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0412108

Comment: This is relevant Anadim. I had seen this paper before, but I am looking for a more detailed presentation of the stuff. By the way, very good reference! 

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read Section 6 of: 
[Clustering with Bregman Divergences. Banerjee et al.](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v6/banerjee05b.html) In particular, in that section the authors develop a rate distortion theory using Bregman divergences.

The reason I mention this paper is because both squared Euclidean distance and KL-Divergence are Bregman divergences; Mutual information is the Bregman Information corresponding to KL-Divergence.